# Does anyone know how to use delete method in API using by Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to confirm how to use 'axios' in 'nuxt.js'.
I used sample data,
I really want to know how to use 'axios' method in 'nuxt.js' using typescript.

Post method was success, so I thought delete method is same code as Post method.
But delete method didn't work.
I don't know how can i fix this problem.
Does anyone know?code is below.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="3">
        <v-text-field v-model="name"></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="3">
        <v-btn @click="createNewUser">CreateNewUser</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
            {{user.name}}
            <v-btn @click="deleteUser(user.id)">DeleteUser</v-btn>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";
import axios from "axios";

@Component({})
export default class extends Vue {
  users: object[] = [];
  name: string = "";
  
  async mounted() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",{params:{name:'Glenna Reichert'}})
        .then(response=>this.users = response.data)
        .catch(response=>console.log(response));
    axios
  }

  createNewUser() {
    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", { name: this.name })
      .then((response) => this.users.unshift(response.data))
      .catch((response) => console.log(response));
  }
    
  deleteUser(id: any) {
    axios
      .delete("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"+id)
      .then((response) => console.log(response))
      .catch((response) => console.log(response));
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The URL for `axios.delete` is missing a slash between `users` and the ID, resulting in a `404 Not Found` error.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I didn't notice my missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing slash in URL, It's better to use the template literals for reducing your mistakes.

```
async deleteUser(id:any){
   await axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`)
         .then((response) => console.log(response.status))
         .catch((response) => console.log(response.status));
}
```

Comment: I definitely have to use template literals for my issue.
Thank you for your advise! it was really helpful for me.